# Is there a recommended HTML/CSS/JavaScript coding style guide?

Tags: javascript, html, css, coding-style

My team is trying to agree on a common HTML/CSS/Javascript coding style guide.
I found the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml), but nothing similar for HTML or CSS.

I'm specifically interested if there are some recommended class or ID naming conventions that are commonly used.

Comment: [Archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20150603053724/http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) version, [current](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html) version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google actually has its own HTML and CSS style guide now: https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html

Comment: Same for the JavaScript styleguide by Google: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml Both are excellent. The conventions in the JS version probably look very familiar to Java developers due to similarities between JavaDoc and JSDoc.

Comment: dead link; please try to post contents in the post for posterity.

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui [archived](http://web.archive.org/web/20150603053724/http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml) version and [current](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html) version.

Answer (score 4):

For JavaScript, use [Standard Style](https://github.com/feross/standard).

[image: js-standard-style]

Answer (score 1):

In terms of CSS, this is good:
http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/11/useful-guidelines-to-improve-css-coding.html

A personal touch I add to my CSS is tabbing, I think that nested elements should be tabbed for example:

```
table 
{ 
}
  tr
  {
  }
    td
    {
    }
```

You could also use a combination of name concatenating and tabbing with you css e.g.

```
.main
{
}
  .main-title
  {
  }
    .main-title > h1
    {
    }
  .main-content
  {
  }
```

Just found an interesting article on CSS naming:
http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/11/css-coding-semantic-approach-in-naming.html
There's links to 10 different CSS Frameworks, and to 11 CSS naming convention articles.

For JavaScript, I believe that the google style guide you've posted is good.

Comment: Thank you for the links. They are really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

an approch alot of people are using today for some html/css guidance is [object-oriented css](http://oocss.org/). I personally, don't like it how it 'forces' you to some structures/names, but if your team is big, this is for sure a way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

#### https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Mozilla_Coding_Style_Guide

there is no such HTML and CSS style guide, you must learn by yourself.
[this link](http://www.w3.org/standards/) may b useful for you.

another way is use [`validator`](http://validator.w3.org/)  to check you code

Comment: Thanks for the link. It contains some JavaScript coding guides, but nothing about HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of any for HTML/CSS and I'm not sure you really need one.

The major point of style guides is to make code quickly skim readable by using familiar visual layouts and naming conventions, so that developers know what something does because that's how they would have laid it out/named it too. HTML/CSS offer a lot less scope for variation in the way things are done compared to a complex language like JavaScript. HTML being markup and strictly nested forces a particular layout, and CSS mostly only has one code construct, so you're left with names, which because they are not descriptive of actions and don't deal with data, rarely need to get very complex.

Regarding JavaScript, as with any language, you need to choose a set of standards and stick to them. It doesn't really matter which ones as someone will always prefer a different set. Consistency is key, so the only other thing to look for is a set that match those of any large libraries you are working with. One project I work on has its own rules for PHP which must also be used for JavaScript. This makes it look weird when library code uses camelCase() and other code uses words_separated_by_underscores() for function names.

Another, minor issue may be that your favourite IDE may or may not have good support for enforcing a particular set of standards through its auto-formatting/error flagging. One-click fixes for sloppy code are a real luxury sometimes!

Comment: Great answer, thank you. Regarding CSS class/id naming I can't decide between camelCase and names-separated-with-dashes.

Comment: I'd recommend dashes, based on the fact XHTML is all lower case and all other parts of CSS are dash-separated e.g. font-size, background-color. One other thing I didn't mention is that it's helpful to instantly know at a glance what language you're looking at, so camelCase may confuse things slightly if used for CSS.

Comment: Thanks! The JQuery UI libraries we use, also use dashes. So we decided for dashes.

Comment: I can't agree with this. CSS and HTML can become _very_ complex on big projects. Because every CSS class is global a good naming convention is really essential here and thats why ideas like BEM are so popular. With web components or frameworks like Angular and Polymer we move more complexity to the HTML, so good conventions become necessary here, too.